# WebDriver unable to locate element (link/Java)

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium to navigate a webpage which has a link called "Mail", using WebDriver (just recently switched from RC to WebDriver).  I want to click on the link but the testcase always fails with the error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"link text","selector":"Mail"}

When inspecting the element with Firebug I get the following HTML:

`<a href="url/New-Doc" target="_top" fahidden="false" faswid="e-switcher-mail" faprop="p-e-switcher-function-id">Mail</a>`

This is the Java which attempts to click the link:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Mail"));    
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I can see that the element is present on screen but still, the test case fails.

**Does anyone know what I might be missing here or an alternative way to find the link element?**

Comment: you could try `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='url/New-Doc']")).click();`. If that doesn't work is your link embedded inside an iframe? Or in some sort of hover-menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via XPath. Example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("/a[text()='Mail']"));
```

Would also be worthwhile double checking to ensure there are no iframes on the page.

Comment: You were right on the iframes, needed to execute driver.switchTo().frame("MainFrame"); before trying to click the link, thanks!

Comment: You're `iframe` comment saved me a lot of headache. Thanks for explaining how you got to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Even i had faced this situation once. View your source code and find out if the element you are looking for is inside a frame. If yes, first switch to the frame in which the element is located and then look out for the element. It worked this way for me.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best workaround I found for cases like this:

- Open Firefox with Selenium IDE installed
- In firefox open the test page
- Run selenium IDE, start recording and click the link
- Selenium IDE will offer you ways how to locate the target. If you switch to relative XPath, it should do the magic (Or, in my cases, it always helped)